# Certain Java files in Android Studio not showing up on GitHub Desktop

Tags: java, git, android-studio, github-desktop

I have a project in Android Studio, and whatever changes I make in the application in Android Studios usually shows up in GitHub Desktop to push. Below is a screenshot of a history of revisions I've made:

[image]

However, at a certain point, I've made java classes in the application that are not being accounted for in GitHub Desktop. The classes that I am unable to push to my repository are highlighted in yellow:

[image]

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the commands:

- Go to root directory of project and run `git status` to list uncommitted files.
- Run `git add .` to add all the files to track.
- Run `git commit -m "your message"` to commit files in current track.
- Run `git pull origin branch_name` to get updated data from that branch. (branch_name is your current branch name.)
- Run `git push origin branch_name` to push all committed files.

Now you check status by `git status` Hope all files will be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) on the new files?  You can't push new files if you don't add them first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for the answer.

I had the same issue while using Android Studio. In my case .gitignore file at the repo's main directory had a line that pointed to /app folder of my project. I just removed it and problem solved.

In general, you can have multiple .gitignore files so follow the below steps to fix this type of issue:

1. Go to your root directory of the git repo.
2. Search for all .gitignore files (In my case I found 3 files. )
3. See which of the files is causing the issue by simply commenting all the lines of a file.
4. Once you have the identified the file, now search for the line that is pointing to the files that you are interested and remove it.